# Parameterized SQL Server inserts very slow

Tags: c#, sql

I had to recently change the data access layer of my application to use parameterized SQL instead of dynamic. For SQL Server, this means sending in values as command parameters instead of performing string replacements in code.

For a process that needs to insert 27k rows, the commands are broken up so that there are 96 inserts per command, totaling 2016 input variables. This is taking ~2.5 seconds per command. Before this, each command had about 1000 inserts and took .5 seconds on average.

What can I do to optimize this process?

**c#**

```
foreach (ParameterObject po in sqlParam.ColumnParameters)
{
    SqlParameter spParam = new SqlParameter();
    spParam.Direction = po.Direction;
    spParam.SqlDbType = ConvertToDBType(po.Type);
    spParam.ParameterName = po.ParameterName;

    if (po.FieldSize != null)
        spParam.Size = po.FieldSize;

    spParam.Value = po.Value;
    command.Parameters.Add(spParam);
}

// execute command and get return value
oiRowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

T-SQL insert snippet:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4, COLUMN5, COLUMN6, COLUMN7, COLUMN8, COLUMN9, COLUMN10, COLUMN11, COLUMN12, COLUMN13, COLUMN14, COLUMN15, COLUMN16, COLUMN17, COLUMN17, COLUMN18, COLUMN19, COLUMN20) 
VALUES (@MYTABLE_COLUMN1_0D1BC2AB84884349A6912AB92FF60CE3, @MYTABLE_COLUMN2_06C42777A52A424192C7440D9F81E2ED, @MYTABLE_COLUMN3_D758A1B77F274CE8A69C830BD10B9A23, @MYTABLE_COLUMN4_A235ED1E13D34155B0A6291E88DF2E4D, @MYTABLE_COLUMN5_71413333777143A4AD9AFA3B8067433B, @MYTABLE_COLUMN6_E14252A4AD6E48B281B255D6814EB5E3, @MYTABLE_COLUMN7_7B5B12B20BBE43BFBC6C7924E2CFE08F, @MYTABLE_COLUMN8_74F9FB0AB9B54F4B8A874DE739089DF2, @MYTABLE_COLUMN9_9441985F2B464523A75081AD74EA2F18, @MYTABLE_COLUMN10_6F17E6806F2A4E32B20E1915AF2A09B8, @MYTABLE_COLUMN11_B91E1549AA0B4FD7B3E1395D8D9CA0A2, @MYTABLE_COLUMN12_E9B2DE8B17D24725B866E2A8505C0E9A, @MYTABLE_COLUMN13_814D51588A73478790D8B7C16D60A736, @MYTABLE_COLUMN14_3CE557074F784B378DE983D01FA221FF, @MYTABLE_COLUMN15_5CE50C3C97C0493A92CA411C2635C3AF, @MYTABLE_COLUMN16_9C143DBFAA2C4517A275DE1845760A5C, @MYTABLE_COLUMN17_B6E6D88C228D419FBEDD9EA866670A09, @MYTABLE_COLUMN17_E2479C7F52464CE3994DC75EBABD0B36, @MYTABLE_COLUMN18_23444536201A4E64898BFBD724FFD0A0, @MYTABLE_COLUMN19_35936A60BD294FDB97A62EE32C4DDA6D, @MYTABLE_COLUMN20_E87315891E8E4AE58754595C4C825288);

IF @@ROWCOUNT <> 1 
BEGIN 
    RAISERROR('-20001 Table: MYTABLE Function Type: Insert', 16, 1)
    RETURN 
END;

INSERT INTO MYTABLE (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4, COLUMN5, COLUMN6, COLUMN7, COLUMN8, COLUMN9, COLUMN10, COLUMN11, COLUMN12, COLUMN13, COLUMN14, COLUMN15, COLUMN16, COLUMN17, COLUMN17, COLUMN18, COLUMN19, COLUMN20) 
VALUES (@MYTABLE_COLUMN1_BF6CCBB453A444838F7ED12CB48916E7, @MYTABLE_COLUMN2_E3159D1012C3414595C36DCC9D93CA40, @MYTABLE_COLUMN3_A17320C11DB040AA9EED31B2CCA3CAEE, @MYTABLE_COLUMN4_C8BA776010674AE1BFB3606AD3B80F27, @MYTABLE_COLUMN5_447E68BF44E34AF4B392B85E9F5C8CE2, @MYTABLE_COLUMN6_4D66B26D024C447D8EDB45B619C9ADEA, @MYTABLE_COLUMN7_F341652C63714031923B9C06BB9379DB, @MYTABLE_COLUMN8_E329040EE254465CB44B75A1C01BC0E9, @MYTABLE_COLUMN9_DBEB6C97DD55473D9D818A6A640A11DF, @MYTABLE_COLUMN10_27BB9F25659244BA8CB0F9E7B6B16CE3, @MYTABLE_COLUMN11_87E43C9094BB403695B224C9FC7AA27A, @MYTABLE_COLUMN12_4F958FE87BF34F62BC38BE87BD7A209D, @MYTABLE_COLUMN13_158AF0196D6D4B8FB1AA92287A34ED2E, @MYTABLE_COLUMN14_FF1EFDFA067C4CD998A52B96F9DEBF43, @MYTABLE_COLUMN15_A3FCF4F6943B4D41986AD226A403A420, @MYTABLE_COLUMN16_04E3D88ED6214A8B97E357E2626248A0, @MYTABLE_COLUMN17_3CB9F2328D304212B58930FAA55081DF, @MYTABLE_COLUMN17_0CF8E3BB79424EA389FCEEC46BDAEB1C, @MYTABLE_COLUMN18_7092C63513F0465CB430181E68B92BD6, @MYTABLE_COLUMN19_96D96C8F70BD4B1191FA37B0D75048BA, @MYTABLE_COLUMN20_7AB75F13809B48F8A37A9BBBF5A02DF5);

IF @@ROWCOUNT <> 1 
BEGIN 
    RAISERROR('-20001 Table: MYTABLE Function Type: Insert', 16, 1)
    RETURN 
END;
```

Comment: To insert 27k records quickly, use bulk insert.  Also look at SQL Profiler while performing the insert to identify where the slowdown is occurring.

Comment: Are you recreating the parameters for every instance of the statement? You don't need to do that, add them once and than just change the values.

Comment: @stickybit yes # variables = # columns * # inserts per command. Wouldn't I have to execute inserts one by one to accomplish what you're suggesting?

Comment: Not necessarily, but it can get complicated then. Unless the number of your statements is divisible by the number you want to send at once you have to handle the last batch differently. But I don't think there's (too) much gain in sending more that one of them at a time. You might want to first [`Prepare()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare?view=netframework-4.7.2) the command and than just change the values of the parameters per iteration. Like that only the changed values should be transferred and the DBMS won't have to reparse everything.

Comment: With bulk insert you will insert the data in batches, thus speeding the process a lot. If for some reason you cannot bulk insert, reuse the command as already suggested. Those 2 seconds are weird anyway. If the database is on the same network shouldn't happen. Database locks behind the scenes?

Comment: Apart from BulkInsert (for which see SqlBulkCopy class), there are two other options, table valued parameters (in MS SQL since 2008) and the older XML (sorry can't remember when this was first supported). All three will be faster than single inserts.

Comment: Do you mean the old method was dynamic using Entity Linq?  Entity is much quicker than the SQL Client class.  How quickly do same execute using SQL Query?  Do you think using a stored procedure will be quicker?